# CSS content-visibility property and strange scrollbar behavior

Tags: css, scrollbar

I looked at [the new CSS property `content-visibility`](https://web.dev/content-visibility/) available on Google Chrome 85, and added it to my stylesheets to improve the rendering performance on my site:

```
.my-page-section {
  content-visibility: auto;
}
```

The problem is with the scrollbar. When I drag the scrollbar from top to the bottom, it kind of "lags": the cursor reaches the bottom of the screen, but the scrollbar still is not at the bottom of the page. To get to the bottom of the page, I need to release the mouse, move it up, and drag the scrollbar down several times.

Reading the article linked above, I saw the `contain-intrinsic-size` CSS property. Adding it with a reasonable value reduces the problem with the scrollbar, but it still happens. I think it is because my app generates dynamic content and no HTML div with the class "my-page-section" will have the same size:

```
.my-page-section {
  content-visibility: auto;
  contain-intrinsic-size: 250px;
}
```

My question is: how can I improve my page rendering performance with the content-visibility property, without getting in the way of our users that prefer to drag the scrollbar over using the mouse wheel?

Comment: I'm wondering this too. Thinking of going down the route of a `MutationObserver` to change the property to `content-visibility: visible` once it has been rendered, but I'm not sure how to set `contain-intrinsic-size` without good guessing

Comment: This is a common issue with lazy loading and rendering content in a page. The reality is the scrollbar size and the position of the thumb is a % of the height to represent where the content is respective to the page height. When additional content is rendered the height changes, thus the thumb will jump. I don't think the average user will notice or care. So I would not worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

You should mock up candidates for a design solution. A consequence of dynamic height is a variable scroll height.

1. Re-design pages to group content categories in columns with tiles of
   a fixed size.
2. Parse content after page load to set an accurate contain-intrinsic-size. This may not save 25ms on the first paint, but for the total session it may save time.
3. Explore better applications for this user-level setting: apps using off-screen canvas, onion-skin type apps, scrollbar-agnostic touchscreens.
4. Petition the W3C and browser vendors to resolve this matter appropriately.